# OS 9 showing OS 8 desktop folder

Tags: powerpc, classic-mac-os

I've installed OS X 10.4 Tiger, OS 8.6 and OS 9.2 on three different partitions on a G3 iMac. All clean installs from CD. If I place an alias on the desktop while in OS 8, it shows when I boot into OS 9. The same with OS 9 aliases showing in OS 8. From Tiger I can see that the aliases are in the correct Desktop Folders on the OS 8 and 9 partitions.

Can anyone explain what I'm seeing, and is there a way to disable it so OS 8 and OS 9 function independently?

Comment: Do you mean that a Desktop alias on the OS 8 volume also appears on the Desktop of the OS 9 volume, when booted?

Comment: @benwiggy Exactly. And vice versa.

Comment: What is the path that the alias points to?

Comment: @benwiggy Not just one. Any alias to any app placed on the OS 8 desktop when booted into OS 8 will also show on the OS 9 desktop when booted into OS 9.

Comment: It's been 25 years, but things worked very differently in Classic MacOS, particularly the Desktop. You'll need to read up about how the Desktop works. IIRC, there's an invisible database file somewhere.